# accessing namespaced object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

[updated]
given object:

```
var node = {
  'comments': 'http://example.com/post/#comments',
  'slash:comments': '143',
}
```

One can access the 'title' parameter using indexed access or dot notation:

```
node["comments"]  // 'http://example.com/post/#comments'
node.comments     // 'http://example.com/post/#comments'
```

But with the namespaced property, only the indexed access is available:

```
node["slash:comments"]  // '143'
node.slash:comments     // javascript syntax error
```

Is there a way in javascript to access a namespaced property using dot notation?

It seems incongruous that property keys can be any string value when using associative array access but is limited to variable name syntax when using dot notation - is there a W3C spec defining this?

[update]
Why @Bergi? The above object is a segment of an object generated by an XML to JSON library for the following XML (RSS2.0 feed format):

```
<slash:comments>143</slash:comments>
<comments>http://example.com/post/#comments</comments>
```

Another library generates this object, where all properties can be accessed via dot notation.

```
'comments': [
  'http://example.com/post/#comments',
  {
    '__prefix': 'slash',
    '__text': '143'
  }
]
```

Does anyone know if there is an effort to standardize transformations of XML to JSON?  What is the most widely used or acceptable library?

Comment: Why do you use such a thing at all? There are no namespaces in JS. Would you expect blanks (such as `node["slash comments"]`) to work with dots as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's true, you must follow the JS dot notation format. In your case:

```
var node = {
  'comments': 'http://example.com/post/#comments',
  'slash':{
      comments': '143'
   }
}
console.log(node.slash.comments);
```

The closest I could find for documentation http://www.w3.org/wiki/Objects_in_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

No. What are you calling as a namespaced property using this notation, with `:`, it is still just a String. As `:` is a special characters on JS, you can't do that using dot notation. If you use `_` instead of `:` to define your namespaces you will be able to do that.